# Terraform: set max_buckets in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, terraform

I need to set max_buckets in elasticsearch aws. So far I've tried using a max_buckets key right in the module block, but that didn't work. Next try was using advanced_options

```
module "elasticsearch" {
  es_version = "6.3"
  advanced_options = { 
    "search.max_buckets" = "123456"
  }
```

But this causes:

```
Error: Unsupported argument

  on elasticsearch.tf line 14, in module "elasticsearch":
  14:   advanced_options = {
```

How can I set max_buckets?

Answer (score 1):

Which module are you using? The [aws_elasticsearch_domain](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/elasticsearch_domain.html) resource has the `advanced_options` argument.

> **advanced_options** - Key-value string pairs to specify advanced configuration options. Note that the values for these configuration options must be strings (wrapped in quotes).

```
resource "aws_elasticsearch_domain" "es" {
  domain_name           = "${var.domain}"
  elasticsearch_version = "6.3"

  advanced_options = {
    "rest.action.multi.allow_explicit_index" = "true"
  }
}
```

Could you provide more details about your implementation? It seems in your example that a double-quote is missing for `search.max_buckets` and if you're using a module, I think you should pass the `source` argument.

Comment: > It seems in your example that a double-quote: 

typing error just in the example!